# Convert logical formula to DNF in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, algorithm

I need a function to convert a formula like this:

```
(A = 1 AND (B > 4 OR C > 5)) OR (A = 3 AND (B > 4 OR C > 10))
```

to a DNF format. The formula could be more complex that this example.

Any help to find an algorithm or code about this conversion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean `BNF` instead of `DNF` ?

Comment: No, I mean DNF (Disjunctive Normal Form)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the [Class Library for Boolean Function Manipulation](http://dispatcher.swu.bg/BCL/), which is a .NET library to containing methods to convert a formula to a truth table and to convert a truth table to DNF.

Alternatively there's the .NET Framework 4.6.2. reference implementation that converts [decision diagrams to DNF](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Entity/System/Data/Common/Utils/Boolean/Converter.cs). This might be helpful if you want to implement your own in VB.Net (or in a C# library to call from VN.Net).